# Removing/disabling a single SQL instance on a failover cluster?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, clustering, failover-cluster-instance

I need to retire a single SQL instance on a (classic) failover cluster while leaving other SQL instances running. SQL version is 2012 in case that matters, but this could come up for other versions in the future.

The other instances will eventually be retired as well, so I'm more concerned about ease and speed than I am about leaving bits behind (which will be cleaned up when the entire cluster is retired). For this reason, if possible I'd prefer not to go through the entire setup/uninstall wizard on each host (which could involve disruption to the other running instances).

To do this on a standalone server I would just stop and disable the SQL Server service; would that work on a failover cluster? Or would I simply remove the role from Failover Cluster Manager, *then* disable the relevant services?

Or am I going to have to do this the "right" way with a scheduled maintenance window and digging up the original install disk?

Comment: I'd do it the "official" way, anything else is going to leave a mess in the registry and potentially cluster database as well.